# Replace/overwrite local SQLite database file [WP8]

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I' ve got a local pre-populated SQLite database file in my main project folder from which I get the needed data in my application. I establish a connection using:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("mydb.sqlite");
```

This file gets somehow updated (not locally & not by me or the user) so, after checking for new versions in my application, I have to overwrite my .sqlite file with the new one I download for that purpose.

(Also, there is a property called 'Build Action' which needs to be changed after adding a new db file.)

Is that possible? If so, have you got any suggestions?

edit:

I've managed to store the downloaded file in LocalStorage and then tried to copy and replace my database using this code:

> StorageFile originalFile = await
>   ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("mydb.sqlite");
>               StorageFile downloadedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("mydb2.sqlite");
>
> await downloadedFile.CopyAndReplace(originalFile);

Now I'm getting this error:

'Windows.Storage.StorageFile' does not contain a definition for 'CopyAndReplace' and no extension method 'CopyAndReplace' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile' could be found

It's strange because it works fine in a new project I created. Could that be a conflict in the assembly references?

Comment: Cant understand the question, may be it will help if you explain the exact problem that is blocking you.. Cant download the sdf or cant overwrite the file? or any specific errors??

Comment: just edited my question